# Inno Setup questions about environment variables and UAC elevation

Tags: inno-setup

I have two problems with INNO Setup?

1. How do I check if an env. variable exists and has a value? (I'm interested in %VS90COMNTOOLS%)
2. How do I run the installer with elevated rights? (Display the UAC window and ask for more rights)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1, you can use the built-in Pascal script and the API function [GetEnvironmentVariable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683188(VS.85).aspx) documented via MSDN.

For 2, name your executable Setup.exe, or use the [Setup] section's PrivilegesRequired entry as documented in InnoSetup's [FAQ](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php) page.